# Fail2Ban unbans after 10 minutes. bantime none warning?

Tags: linux, nginx, fail2ban

having a bit of an issue with fail2ban filters, for some reason it unbans after 10 minutes even though I set the ban length to one year. Could you assist a brother out?

jail.local declaration for filters:

```
[nginx-proxy]
enabled  = true
#port    = http,https
action   = iptables-multiport[name=NoProxy, port="http,https"]
filter   = nginx-proxy
logpath  = /etc/nginx/logs/*access*.log
bantime  = 31536000 # 1 year
maxretry = 0

[nginx-shellshock]
enabled  = true
#port    = http,https
action   = iptables-multiport[name=ShellShock, port="http,https"]
filter   = nginx-shellshock
logpath  = /etc/nginx/logs/*access*.log
bantime  = 31536000 # 1 year
maxretry = 0
```

nginx-proxy.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> .* "GET http.*
ignoreregex =
```

nginx-shellshock.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.*\(\s*\)\s*\{[^"]*\}\s*\;[^"]+.*

ignoreregex =
```

Here is my fail2ban.log file

```
2015-10-27 06:21:48,953 fail2ban.jail           [8319]: INFO    Jail 'nginx-auth' started
2015-10-27 06:21:48,981 fail2ban.jail           [8319]: INFO    Jail 'nginx-badbots' started
2015-10-27 06:21:49,022 fail2ban.jail           [8319]: INFO    Jail 'nginx-proxy' started
2015-10-27 06:21:49,062 fail2ban.jail           [8319]: INFO    Jail 'nginx-shellshock' started
2015-10-27 13:17:40,737 fail2ban.filter         [8319]: INFO    [nginx-shellshock] Found 108.171.178.73
2015-10-27 13:17:41,667 fail2ban.actions        [8319]: NOTICE  [nginx-shellshock] Ban 108.171.178.73
2015-10-27 13:17:41,747 fail2ban.filter         [8319]: INFO    [nginx-shellshock] Found 108.171.178.73
2015-10-27 13:17:41,747 fail2ban.filter         [8319]: INFO    [nginx-shellshock] Found 108.171.178.73
2015-10-27 13:17:41,880 fail2ban.actions        [8319]: NOTICE  [nginx-shellshock] 108.171.178.73 already banned
2015-10-27 13:27:42,572 fail2ban.actions        [8319]: NOTICE  [nginx-shellshock] Unban 108.171.178.73
```

On fail2ban service restart, I also get an error about shellshock bantime being set to none:

```
2015-10-28 00:29:31,351 fail2ban.transmitter    [11600]: WARNING Command ['set', 'nginx-shellshock', 'bantime', 'None'] has failed. Received ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'",)
```

Greatly appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire issue was dedicated around me using the comment tag, which apparently in fail2ban configurations comments the entire line. Either change the hash tag to a semi colon or put it on another line.